# Symfony2 : Display a certain number fields from collection without button to generate

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a entity who have a start date and a end Date like 2013 and 2016.
So i want autmatically display four fields directly, according to years!
With allow_add, we must click on a button to display a field!
How can we go about doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try pre-filling your entity with start-/end-dates? Just add pre-filled values to your entity, and symfony/form will do the rest.

Comment: what do you mean by pre-filling @MichaelHirshler

Comment: Create an entity, add the start-/end-dates as you wish (from 2013 till 2016 as for your example) and put it into your form (while creating).